# Remover duplicados en un archivo Csv batch

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo el siguiente código, funciona bien pero si contiene en alguna línea el siguiente caracter `!` termina borrando toda la información o dejándolo erróneo

**Ejemplo de entrada del archivo Csv.**

```
Column 1    Column2    Column3
Hello        0001       abc  
hello        0002       fge
heLLo        0001       abc
hello!       0003       geg
```

**Lo que tendría que hacer.**

```
Column 1    Column2    Column3
Hello        0001       abc  
hello        0002       fge
hello!       0003       geg
```

**Lo que hace mi codigo.**

```
Column 1   
hello03
```

**El Codigo**

```
    @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set src=Clean\File.csv
set line=
(for /F "delims=" %%L in ('sort %src%') do (
   if not ~!line!~ == ~%%L~ echo %%L
   set line=%%L
)) > "%Final.csv
```

Comment: bienvenido a SO en español. Por favor, considera [edit] tu pregunta y traducirla antes de que sea cerrada o puesta en espera.